# Number of unique triangles with sides given in an array

Tags: algorithm

I want to find the maximum number of "unique" triangles (Each array element can be used only once), by brute force (either O(N^3) or recursive bactracking). What approach should be taken?

Comment: As it stands I don't think there's enough information in this question for anyone to answer it. Could you explain further, show us what you've already tried and any specific problems you've encountered. What language are you trying to do this in?

Comment: I'm doing it in C++. I should add that the triangles should be valid.

Comment: Side lengths are given in the array. Maximum number of triples that form a valid triangle is wanted. (a<(b+c) && b<(a+c) && c<(a+b)). Each side length can only be used once, that is triangles' sides should be disjoint. If there are duplicate side lengths, same side length can be used more than once.

Comment: Since you are asking brute-force approach, I didn't see the problem. What's problem of O(n^3) algorithm?

Comment: With O(N^3), I couldn't establish the condition that each array element will be used only once. Maybe it's simple, but couldn't see how.

Comment: Note that if a side has been used once in a triangle, it cannot be used in another triangle.

Answer (score 2):

First assume that all edges have length in positive integers. (For real numbers, the interval is *half-open-half-closed* and makes it messier to reason about.)

Basically, if we find an effective way to get the number of edges with length in range `[a,b]` for every `0<=a<=b`, we can process it as:

```
    edgeList = sort edgeList by length ascending order
    foreach ( edge1 in edgeList )
        foreach ( edge2 in edgeList where [edge2 >= edge1] )
            answer = answer + count_edge_number ( edge2 , edge1+edge2-1 );
    return answer;
```

Therefore we just need such a way. To do this, you just need to sort the edges by length in ascending order, use binary search for the indices (subscription) of the lower and upperbound of the interval in question. (That's to say, for any `[a,b]`, use binary search to find the largest `i` with `element[i]<a` and smallest `j` with `element[j]<=b`). This works in `O(logN)`.

Therefore your task could be achieved in `O(N^2LogN)`, much better than strawman `O(N^3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a map (hashmap should be fine) with end-point mapped to side. So each side will have 2 entries - one for each end-point. Now you're able to efficiently look up all sides starting from any given end-point.

Some basic pseudo-code:

```
// map[X] is all unused sides with X as end-point
// markAsUsed should also remove the side from the map
// markAsUnused should also add the side to the map

// initial function call for any unused side
backTrackFunction(anyUnusedSide)

backTrackFunction(side AB)
  if map.isEmpty
    Found a solution.
  markAsUsed(AB)
  for each side AC in map[A]
    if map[C].contains(CB)
      // AB, CB and AC form a triangle
      markAsUsed(CB)
      markAsUsed(AC)
      backTrackFunction(anyUnusedSide)

      // Backtrack
      markAsUnused(CB)
      markAsUnused(AC)
```

The above may have some problems, but it's just intended to be a starting point.